# How to cross reference between different beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, presentations

for my lectures I am preparing beamer presentations.

I would like to include sections (possibly more than one in a single beamer presentation) and to be able to have continuing numbering of definitions, theorems etc in the next beamer presentations. 
I know how to number them in a single presentation but then in the next one the numbering begins from 1 again and I can't refer to a theorem from a previous beamer presentation.

Is there any way of doing this?
Help is much appreciated

Comment: For this you'll probably need a combination of [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount).

Comment: Why not use `\part{}` to split you presentation. If you do this you can show contents for each part separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to cross-reference between two different presentations i.e. to have consecutive numbering for all presentations (as in lecture notes).